# Deployment technique for deploying code on like 50 IIS webservers(asp.net and asp combination)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment

Assume I have 20 servers , with  websites setup on each server IIS.

The code is a mix of asp and asp.net

Now I have website code on each server for each website.// all the websites are same

Assume the website name is www.somewebsite1111.com(just for example)

If i want to deploy code to all the servers, I have to take each server out of load balancer deploy code and then do a IISreset and put back into load balancer, I have to repeat this for 20 times.

Soon the no of servers may become 50 , so the deployment time may take to much time to deploy on each server.

We can not just copy the code to all servers when the servers on load balancer for some reasons.

Based on your experience can you suggest some good solutions for deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently worked on a project with the exact same scenario.

We had 29 web servers (behind web tier load balancer), and 15 app servers (behind app tier load balancer).

We used **[Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732.aspx)** (part of Windows Server - not sure if other Windows OS's have this)

Essentially, you specify which servers are in a particular pool/policy, then a software package can be executed against all of the servers in this pool.

Now, we used MSI's on the group policy console. So it depends how you are packaging/deploying your code. Group Policy is more aimed for "software" (e.g MSI, exe's, etc). Don't think you'd be able to use Web Deploy in this scenario.

Not sure if this is the latest/most recommended way of deploying to a load balanced environment, but thought i'd share my past experience.

Comment: @RPM , we are also using Windows Server , if possible can you explain little bit more

Comment: @RPM , what happens if put all the code in one remote location and point all the websites to that code?? will that lead any IO problems

Comment: @gov - what do you mean "point all websites to that code"? That is not load balancing. That "one remote location" will be hammered for resources, not balanced. Each web server should have it's own code, and the load balancer should use a specific algorithm (e.g round robin) to figure out which server to point to per HTTP request.

Comment: I'm just thinking, maybe this question is better suited for www.serverfault.com

Comment: @RPM , you are right , the remote server will be hammered for resources// We are already using netscalar loader balancer and all , i am just asking about deploying builds etc as there is discussiong going on

Comment: Well you setup GP on 1 server per tier. So we had a "WEBGP" box. We remote desktop'd to that box, installed the MSI via GP, then GP would install the MSI's on each machine, and reboot them. That's all that is required. You don't even need to remote desktop to the servers at all. And of course since they're rebooted, IIS will pick up the new changes. Of course if you want *rolling* deployments, you'll need to split up your pool into groups. Is there anything else you need to know?

Comment: @RPM thanks for all the  info and your patience, i gave +1 and i will wait if some others gives any ideas , otherwise i will come back and mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used it myself, but I think you might want to have a look at the [IIS Web Deployment](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) tool.

Answer (score 1):

If dealing with WebFarms you should really check out the new Web Farm Framework, free for download at: http://www.iis.net/download/webfarmframework

To see some info: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/08/introducing-the-microsoft-web-farm-framework.aspx